# It is possible to program Linino to send HTTP requests and then use the returned values in sketch?

Tags: http, request, arduino, client, cpu-usage

I am new to using Arduino Yun and I would like to know if it is possible to run a command from the Arduino sketch in order to make (probably, through the Bridge Library) Linino to execute a HTTP Request to a remote server. Then I would like to know if it is possible to use the returned values in that Arduino sketch.

In other words, I would like to delegate the task of retrieving values from the web to the Linux side and the usage of the retrieved data to the sketch.

If it is possible, how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Arduino IDE there is an example scetch: File>Example>Bridge>HTTP client.  Have you looked at that? It retrieves the content of a text document hosted on the Arduino site and prints it to the Serial Monitor.